# Enterprise Library CacheFactory.GetCacheManager Throws Null Ref

Tags: c#, configuration, enterprise-library

I'm trying to convert an application using the 1.1 version of the Enterprise Library Caching block over to the 2.0 version.  I think where I'm really having a problem is that the configuration for the different EntLib pieces was split out over several files.  Apparently, this used to be handled by the **ConfigurationManagerSectionHandler**, but is now obsolete in favor of the built-in configuration mechanisms in .NET 2.0.

I'm having a hard time finding a good example of how to do this configuration file splitting, especially in the context of EntLib.  Has anyone else dealt with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was the configuration.  I found a good example of the normal, one-file approach here:  http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/31158/0/page/2

Using an external config file is actually trivial once you figure out the syntax for it.  Ex.:

In Web.config:

```
<cachingConfiguration configSource="cachingconfiguration.config" />
```

In cachingconfiguration.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="Default Cache Manager">
    <backingStores>
        <add name="inMemory" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching" />
    </backingStores>
    <cacheManagers>
        <add name="Default Cache Manager" expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds = "60" maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging ="50" numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="10" backingStoreName="inMemory" />
    </cacheManagers>
</cachingConfiguration>
```

Hopefully this helps somebody!